# How can I get and install the asa utility on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I am new to Ubuntu.  How can I get and install the "asa" utility (for interpreting carriage-control characters in output from Fortran programs)?  It does not appear to be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't find it using search in the software centre.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: See weather is it the first one in this list - [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libasa). If so, you can install it in the terminal with the command `sudo apt-get install libasa-perl`

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=68078), you won't get it in the repositories anymore, you will have to download it from source and recompile.

You can download the tarball from [here](ftp://sunsite.unc.edu/pub/Linux/devel/lang/fortran)(the `asa-1.1.tar.gz` file). And then extract the file by right-clicking on the tarball and clicking on "Extract here".

Now you need to modify the `Makefile` since the `MANDIR` variable in the file is incorrect as of a debian system. Open the file using your favourite editor and go to line no 4 which reads as:

```
MANDIR = /usr/man/man1
```

and correct it to:

```
MANDIR = /usr/share/man/man1
```

Now open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and to the location where you have extracted the tarball and type the following:

```
make
```

to compile the source files and create the binaries and then

```
sudo make install
```

to move the binaries to the appropriate location.

After this you should be able to use `asa`.